# How do I integrate Firebase.Crashlytics on my Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

Can any one help me with integrating Firebase.Crashlytics on a Xamarin.Forms project for iOS.
It is working fine for me on Android but on iOS I am facing issues.
Note that I have performed the following steps on iOS :-

1. Added Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics Nuget package to my iOS project.
2. Added GoogleService.plist file
3. Made a dependency service for iOS
4. Added the following code to initialize the nuget :-

   ```
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            Crashlytics.Configure();
            Fabric.Fabric.SharedSdk.Debug = true;
            Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Crash();
   ```

**Update**

I have followed all the steps in the below mentioned link :-
https://keithbeattyblog.wordpress.com/2019/06/16/xamarin-forms-adding-google-firebase-crashylitics/
Still nothing works.

When I follow the steps written in the above article I face issues where I am unable to build my project due to the 'Xamarin.Build.Download' NuGet package. Also I face issues where I am unable to deploy the solution to my Simulators because it doesn't allow me select a simulator to run the App.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Last time I checked (not long ago) you could not get C# stacktrace using `Crashlytics` making error reports very cryptic to troubleshoot. Have you consider using app center?

Comment: Hello Claudio,  Thanks for answering the OPs question.  If you cannot get a stack trace then what's the purpose of Crashlytics / iOS?  What does it give?

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you want still go with the old Fabric implementation?
You must be aware that the Fabric Crashlytics version is deprecated, right?

All of us have received a mail from Google informing that:

> We are writing to let you know that the Fabric Crashlytics SDK is now deprecated and will continue reporting your app's crashes until
> November 15, 2020. After this date, the Fabric Crashlytics SDK and
> beta versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending crash
> reports for your app.What happened?
> We are replacing Fabric Crashlytics SDKs and beta versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDKs with the generally available Firebase
> Crashlytics SDKs.What's Next?
> To continue getting crash reports in the Firebase console, make sure to upgrade your apps to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK versions
> 17.0.0+ for Android, 4.0.0+ for iOS, and 6.15.0+ for Unity before November 15, 2020.Android

So everything is going to change soon, and you shouldn't use the Fabric solution anymore, especially for new projects.

You can find the new official NuGet package here, but it is still in preview:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics/117.0.0-preview02

This is the official repository issue to add comments:
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/956

When you'll add this new package and the google-services.json you will need to change the following in your old code:

- Every `CrashLytics.Crashlytics` reference will be just `FirebaseCrashlytics`.
- No initialization is needed, you can get the `FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance` anywhere
- To log an exception you will need to use the `RecordException` method instead of the old `LogException`
- `SetUserIdentifier` is changed to `SetUserId`, and `SetUserName` is no longer there
- There is no method to crash on purpose anymore, so now you have to simply throw any exception you want if you wanna test your implementation

Maybe I'm missing something, but basically, that's all.

Comment: Hi, is there any tutorial covering this using the new nuget?

Comment: You just need to add the nuget and use it right away. 
If you want to test that everything is set up ok and working, you can throw an exception from outside a try-catch block and go to the firebase console to see the result, but in my experience, it may take some time until you see the first exception logged. If you want to know how to log something, you can take a look at the official guide from the guys @Google. You can use the same methods described there (after changing the case, as usual) : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android

Comment: but this library isnt cross platform right? it is only for Android? because it isnt possible to install it on .net standard shared library. So we need to go with DI to use in the shared library?

Answer (score -4):

Update `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics` to version [4.0.0-beta.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics/4.0.0-beta.7)

and in your app delegate just call

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent(Firebase.Analytics.EventNamesConstants.SelectContent, new Dictionary<object, object> {
    { Firebase.Analytics.ParameterNamesConstants.ItemId, "hokisit-ios" },
    { Firebase.Analytics.ParameterNamesConstants.ItemName, "Hokisit iOS" }
});
```

Comment: Is it necessary to sign the App with a proper provisioning profile ?

Comment: Sure, every app should sign with a proper provisioning profile

Comment: The op is asking how to use crashlytics.  You are describing how to use Analytics.

Comment: As per official guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#add-sdk, crashlytics already initialize along with analytics

Comment: another solution from accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878656/4778712