# Xamarin Forms Firebase Crashlytic Doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, crashlytics

Installed nuget

```
Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics 117.3.0
```

Code i call in Android project:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SetUserId("someid");
FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SetCustomKey("MyKey", "MyValue");
FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.Log("Testing log crashlytic");
FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SendUnsentReports();
```

Code i call in Xamarin Forms

```
throw new Exception("Test crashlytic");
```

And i still get this on my firebase console

[image: firebase console]

I also wait for a few hour incase it delayed, but its still doesnt work
I also installed Firebase Analytic and it works fine
Implementation that i followed
[another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428653/10954228)