# Xamarin Crashlytics

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, crashlytics

I need to add Crashlytics to my Xamarin Android application
I have tried this NuGet
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics/
but it doesn't work and I am always stack at this window in firebase
[image]

how can I enable it

Comment: did you install and crash your app as suggested?  It's not going to show you anything until it has a crash report to display

Comment: the docs are for android studio not Xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set your [google-services.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android#3-google-servicesjson) and add following nuget to your Xamarin.Android project

[image]

Comment: thank you, I have tried it and the project runs after solving many errors regarding shrinking but still unable to see crash in firebase console, I have downloaded my google-services.json from firebase console and add it to the project and set the build action to google-service.json but still not working even when I force crash and when to try to 
catch(Java.Lang.Exception ex)
Firebase.Crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.RecordException(ex);
Firebase.Crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SendUnsentReports();
Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval

Comment: finally it works but I think it need some time to be activated thank you again for your help

Comment: Be aware before you update the firebase version, that the latest config i've try and work. If you want to use latest version, give it a try and let us know what happend :)

Comment: You can ignore `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` it will work even without this lib