# How to use Firebase Crashlytics in Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crashlytics

I tried crashlytics setting refer to this guide https://github.com/a-imai/XamarinCrashlyticsUpgradeSample

but i checked adb log, firebase_crashlytics_enabled is false, instller package name is null etc.

i inserted this code in MainActivity OnCreate Method

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
Firebase.Crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(ture);
```

but firebase_crashlytics_enabled was null yet then
I tried other way through manifest but didn't work..

[image]

I want know correctly Way of Firebase Crashlytics Setting

Comment: Check this official guide https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents .

Comment: For `Xamarin.Android` you can follow [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878656/4778712)

Comment: cahyo solution is correctly, it is working!